# How to get user's facebook username or id?

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api

I am building an application in flutter where you can click on someone's name and it'll redirect you to his profile, and I thought of using user's facebook username or id.
From what I learnt, facebook **username is no longer available through facebook graph api**, and the id you get is app-scoped id that differs from real facebook id. The only thing I found regarding this issue was the `link` field through the graph api, but it requires app review, which I don't completely understand how it's done, but even if I had access to the link, it says that it's only available if that person is your friend on facebook, which contradicts with the purpose of my app, is there any way to achieve this goal? I know it seems duplicated, but I only found really old answers and nothing actually helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can retrieve the `user_link` and other permissions through the [facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference), it still requires [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). You can use [FB ID finder](https://findmyfbid.in/) to find the ID.

Then you can launch the facebook app by passing the FB ID into it (fbUrl = the FB ID and fallbackUrl = the normal FB link which is used incase the user doesnt have FB app installed):

```
Future<void> _launchFacebook (String fbUrl, String fallbackUrl) async {
    try{
      bool launched = await launch(fbUrl);
      if(!launched){
        await launch(fallbackUrl);
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      await launch(fallbackUrl);
    }
  }
```

Comment: fb id finder requires to have the facebook id, my question was how can I get the id in the first place